# Mirage serializer drop Ids when include and embed some model

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I have a problem with mirage.

I am defining a serializer extending `ActiveModelSerializer` with `serializeIds: 'always'`, in this case the model is serialized with the relations models *ids*.

But when  i want include some model in the serialized content i use `include: ['someModel']`, in that case the `someModel` is included succesfully, but the *ids* of the rest of relationships are ignored.

How can i include the *ids* too?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I believe this is the default behavior. To override this you could call super on the Serializer's [serialize method](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.3.x/serializers/#serializeresponse-request) and ensure the ids are added to the payload:

```
serialize(post, request) {
  let json = Serializer.prototype.serialize.apply(this, arguments);

  json.post.commentIds = post.commentIds;

  return json;
}
```